# Why won't SparseArray let me store values with the head List?

Tags: functions, core-language, data-structures, sparse-arrays, language-design

When you attempt to define a [`SparseArray`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/SparseArray.html) with elements that have the head [`List`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/List.html) it complains:

```
SparseArray[{1 -> {1, 2, 3}, 2 -> {"a", "b"}}]
```

> SparseArray::valnl: The value specified by the rule 1->{1,2,3} should not be a List. >>
>
> ```
> SparseArray[{1 -> {1, 2, 3}, 2 -> {"a", "b"}}]
> ```

Nevertheless (other) arbitrary expressions are accepted:

```
SparseArray[{1 -> foo[1, 2, 3], 2 -> bar["a", "b"]}]
```

[image]

There does not appear to be any actual limitation of `SparseArray` that prevents it from storing `List` elements.

In fact with a bit of fiddling we *can* get `SparseArray` to hold `List` elements!  First wrap the Lists an additional head so that `SparseArray` accepts them, then use [`Part`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Part.html) to extract the first part of every element, essentially stripping the arbitrary extra heads (`foo`):

```
sa1 = SparseArray[{1 -> foo@{1, 2, 3}, 2 -> foo@{"a", "b"}}];

sa2 = sa1[[All, 1]];
```

We now have a `SparseArray` with `List` elements:

```
sa2 // Head
sa2[[1]] // Head
Head /@ Normal[sa2]
sa2["NonzeroValues"]
```

> ```
> SparseArray
>
> List
>
> {List, List}
>
> {{1, 2, 3}, {"a", "b"}}
> ```

However if we try to use the [`InputForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/InputForm.html) of the expression (as input) it does not work:

```
ToString[sa2, InputForm] // ToExpression
```

> ```
> SparseArray[Automatic, {2}, 0, {1, {{0, 2}, {{1}, {2}}}, {{1, 2, 3}, {"a", "b"}}}]
> ```

Sadly this false equivalence breaks the use of [`Save`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Save.html) and pattern-based manipulation of the object.

Why would `SparseArray` be blocking the use of `List` when apparently any other head is accepted, and when there is internal support for `List` itself?

Comment: Inserting @Rojo into a `SparseArray[]` seems utterly cruel

Comment: @Bill The strange thing is that as I show they *can* be lists if you work around what appears to be an intentional block.  I can't yet figure out why such functionality would/should be disabled however.

Comment: @belisarius they just cloned me and put me in there without attribution

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The basic reason is that once you convert a tensor expression into a `SparseArray`, you've "given control" of all levels of that expression to `SparseArray` to manage on your behalf in an efficient way (the number of levels is the rank of the tensor, to mix jargon).

`SparseArray` will then try to maintain the illusion that those levels are still really there. But that illusion will fall apart if you're allowed to mess around with the rank of the `SparseArray` after it has been constructed. Putting lists inside an existing `SparseArray` is really telling you that you got the dimension of the `SparseArray` wrong (too small) to begin with.

So it's not a technical limitation, it's a conceptual one. If you start messing with the rank of the `SparseArray`, you're going to run into trouble at some point, e.g. `Dimensions` will give the wrong answer. So we do the best we can to enforce the rank stays the same by insisting you don't store lists (e.g., you're only storing 'scalars').

Comment: Thank you as always for your attention.  I am having trouble understanding this explanation however.  Certainly I could see value in a warning message indicating possible misuse, but if you otherwise allow arbitrary expressions to be SparseArray elements I don't see why Lists are any "worse" a compromise of the intended function.  You wrote: "Putting lists inside an existing SparseArray is really telling you that you got the dimension of the `SparseArray` wrong (too small) to begin with."  I think this view limits the application of `SparseArray` and I am not yet convinced beneficially so.

Comment: Quite often I find it useful to store arbitrary elements in a `SparseArray`, and it is inconvenient not to be able to store `List` objects without a container.  The existence of List elements need not imply a two dimensional array; rather a sparse vector with elements, some of which are lists if varying length.  I am trying to see why it is necessary to *block* that flexibility rather than merely cautioning against its misapplication.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard yes, I happen to agree with you, and some other people in the company see it as a mistake, too. But I presented the argument for the current behavior. I'll see if we can revisit that decision.

Comment: Any chance this could be made a System Option?