# How to speed up band matrix-matrix multiplication?

Tags: matrix, performance-tuning, linear-algebra, sparse-arrays

I have a band matrix

```
$HistoryLength = 0;
n = 10000;
b = 300;
k = 300;
a = SparseArray[Flatten[#, 1] &@Table[{i, Mod[i + j, n, 1]}, {i, n}, {j, -b, b}] ->
     RandomComplex[{-1 - I, 1 + I}, n (2 b + 1)]];
```

and a dense matrix

```
u = RandomComplex[{-1 - I, 1 + I}, {n, k}];
```

I want to multiply them as fast as possible

```
v = a.u; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {6.748518, Null}

Visual representation of this multiplication:

```
draw = ArrayPlot[#[[;; ;; 30, ;; ;; 30]], ImageSize -> {Automatic, 200}] &;
Row@{draw[v], " = ", draw[a].draw[u]}
```

[image]

This problem usually comes up when you want to multiply a Hamiltonian by a set of wavefunctions (in a certain basis).

Why I expect a possibility of speeding up? When you multiply dense matrices you can use algorithms like [Strassen algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strassen_algorithm) and use the processor cache to operate with small blocks. The matrix `a` have a dense band. This knowledge can increase performance in contradiction to the sparse matrix of a general form.

Answer (score 6):

## Dense blocks

One can split matrices by blocks and use these blocks as a dense matrices

```
blockSize = 100;
m1[a_] m2[b_] ^:= a.b; 
part = Developer`PartitionMap[If[Length@#@"NonzeroValues" > 0, m1@Normal@#, 0] &, 
    a, {blockSize, blockSize}];
a2.u_ ^:= Flatten[Developer`ToPackedArray[
    part.Developer`PartitionMap[m2, u, blockSize]], 1]
```

I have to introduce the intermediate headers `m1` and `m2` since `SparseArray` [doesn't allow](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/58963/4678) `List` header. Block size should be several times smaller then the width of the band.

```
v2 = a2.u; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {2.581961, Null}

Almost 3x speed up from nothing!

## MKL

MKL has a special function [`mkl_zdiamm`](https://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/hpc/mkl/mklman/GUID-5B40BBEC-E095-4151-A5E1-11CDBB494A2E.htm) for the band matrix - dense matrix multiplication.

However it is 5 times slower then build-in multiplication... But now I know how to use MKL from Mathematica. There was some problems and I'm going to discuss them in a [separate question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/59104/4678).

Comment: @Mr.Wizard passed ahead of me with a question of heads in  `SparseArray` while I fought with MKL =)

Comment: What version are you using? With version 10 on Windows I get 1.75 secs for `a.u` and 1.2 secs for `a2.u` (but with an added overhead of 2.4 secs to calculate `part`)

Comment: @SimonWoods I use version 10 on Linux. I tested on my laptop with Core 2 Quad. Desktop with Core i7 shows even more speed up. Overhead doesn't matter in real calculations, when you multiply a fixed Hamiltonian by wavevectors over and over again. Did you test with the same parameters?