# How to determined intel MKL library version used by current Mathematica?

Tags: linear-algebra, mkl

In Matlab, I can determined which intel MKL is used using a command such as this:

```
>> version -lapack
```

> Intel(R) Math Kernel Library Version 11.2.3 Product Build 
>       20150413 for Intel(R) 64 architecture applications, CNR branch AVX
>       Linear Algebra PACKage Version 3.5.0

```
>> version -blas
```

> Intel(R) Math Kernel Library Version 11.2.3 Product Build 20150413 
>       for Intel(R) 64 architecture applications, CNR branch AVX

So the above tells me Matlab is linked to `MKL 11.2.3`.

How to determined which MKL version is used in *Mathematica*? I kept searching, but could not find a way. I see this on my system (windows 7)

> C:\Program Files\Wolfram Research\Mathematica\11.0\SystemFiles\
>        Kernel\Binaries\Windows-x86-64\mkl_intel_thread.dll

I need to check the MKL version linked with version $11$ and compare it to MKL linked to earlier version of *Mathematica*.

Update:

---

Thanks to comment below by `Szabolcs` it seems File properties->Details shows the info needed. I am not sure though that the `mkl_intel_thread.DLL` is the one actually used by Mathematica. But this is good start.

**Mathematica Version 11**  (no speed boost with rank calculation)

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**version 10.3 Mathematica**  (has speed boost with rank calculation)

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: What if you right click that DLL in Explorer and choose Properties?  On OS X I can't find a shared library with MKL in its name, so I can't try.

Comment: @Szabolcs thanks., I tried it on the file I show there, and it seems under details it shows the version!  I am not sure though that the DLL I am looking at is the one actually used by Mathematica. i.e. I do not know if this mkl_intel_thread.dll is the one, or there is something else around. But this is good start. thanks.

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/41949/18476

Comment: Also: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/59105/18476. But I'm not sure if these work under Windows.